# xpected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path (KOTLIN)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Consider:

```
data class NewsEverything (val name : String,
                           val title : String,
                           val description : String,
                           val url : String,
                           val urlToImage : String,
                           val publishedAt : String,
                           val content : String)

interface EverythingAPI {

    @GET("***")
    suspend fun getEverything() : Response<List<NewsEverything>>

}

private fun loadEverythingData(){
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(EverythingAPI::class.java)

        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = retrofit.getEverything()

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    response.body()?.let {it->
                        newsEverything = ArrayList(it)
                        newsEverything?.let {
                            everythingAdapter = EverythingAdapter(binding.root.context,it)
                            binding.everythingRV.adapter= everythingAdapter
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I know this problem is because I'm using List, but I couldn't do it otherwise. How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see where in the code this happens, but you are parsing JSON containing a single object, as if it was a list. Parse to the correct data structure instead. We could help more, if you showed the code that actually did the parsing.

Comment: It basically means that the response starts with `{` and not as `[`. You are trying to parse it as a list but it is an object. `suspend fun getEverything() : Response<List<NewsEverything>>` should probably be `suspend fun getEverything() : Response<NewsEverything>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you got "expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2" usually indicates that the JSON response from the server is an object ({}) instead of an array ([]). To fix this, you need to update your code to handle the response correctly.

Steps to fix it

- In Android Studio, go to plugin and type `JsonToKotlinClass` here

  [image]
- After you enabled it, restart your Android Studio
- Then click on the folder you want to put your data class in. Right-click and click <kbd>New</kbd>, and then you will the the plugin.

  [image]

Comment: It is incomprehensible near *"you will the the plugin"*.